Azure AD B2C Redirect URI not working except localhost
When the redirect URI is localhost for my Blazor application, it works (locally).
        Scopes = _settings.Scopes.ToStringArray();
        // Create PCA once. Make sure that all the config parameters below are passed
        PCA = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                                    .Create(_settings?.ClientId)
                                    .WithB2CAuthority(_settings?.Authority)
#if !ANDROID
                                    .WithRedirectUri("https://medbase.co.zw/auth")
                                    //.WithRedirectUri("http://localhost")
#endif
                                    .Build();

But when  I use the redirect URI I want to use in production, it doesn't work. It doesn't run the PublicClientApplication Builder but when I test locally with locally, it runs.

The redirect URIs are already added to my Authentication tab under App Registrations. I have tried the other ones i.e. medbase, medbase.co.zw to no avail

When redirect is localhost, are you running the code locally too? I mean, are you selecting Log In from http://localhost? Or is you code in the cloud / on another server?

Yes, from localhost. When I do localhost, it's all locally on my machine.

On your local machine, in a command prompt, run dotnet --version. Check the version against your app runtime Portal->yourWebApp->Configuration.

I have noticed that locally, that withstanding, When I have set the WithRedirectUrl="http://localhost" to anything that is not Localhost, it doesn't work even locally. In my head, it's supposed to run regardless, but it just won't send the token to the right place, but it should run

Have you done something unusual in code in order to use http instead of https?

What is the version of your App?The App is Blazor Server or WASM?

@ArchitectJamie I am using https.

@Harshitha It's blazor server

@TanakaMawere I mean when you're testing using localhost. Your redirect is http and your code you shared above says http.

Ohhhhhhhh, no. The package allows you to use http over localhost, it's an exception they made. I am trying to look for the docs and will paste as an edit here where it says that
